# MySql Insert Query based on Timestamp (delayed insert)

Tags: php, mysql, insert

i need to do `delayed` `mysql insert` into my database based on the time choosen.

Example: `Timestamp` choosen = `"2013-04-03 10:12:00"`

so i want my `insert query` to get executed at this`("2013-04-03 10:12:00")` particular time.

`$qry = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (field) value ($value)");`

i am having a `mysql innoDB` database.

and i will be accepting this `timestamp` value from user from a `HTML+PHP` interface.

and yes, i `dont want` to do `cron jobs`

Comment: MySQL doesn't provide something like that out of the box. But you could simply add those records at any time and then filter them out in subsequent SELECT statements with a WHERE clause like `WHERE field<=Now()`

Answer (score 0):

No option without cron job...

You need a `cron job` setup for `every minute`, in which the query is looking for any matching timestamp for the insert query.

But for every minute `cron job` is not better for DB health if you have more and more data to insert, you should think again about the time interval for better performance.

Comment: this job is not provided by mysql, you have to set this job from your hosted server control panel..

Answer (score 0):

You could insert data into additional table, then use MySQL events to copy records into target table at exact time. For example -

```
CREATE EVENT event1
  ON SCHEDULE AT '2013-04-03 20:00:00'
  DO 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO <table> SELECT * FROM <temp table>;
  TRUNCATE TABLE <temp table>;
END
```

[Using the Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html).